# How to visualize colmap export [images.txt] in blender?

Tags: python, math, 3d, blender, multiview

I have a colmap export of the camera pose file which named "[images.txt](https://colmap.github.io/format.html#images-txt)".

```
# Image list with two lines of data per image:
#   IMAGE_ID, QW, QX, QY, QZ, TX, TY, TZ, CAMERA_ID, NAME
#   POINTS2D[] as (X, Y, POINT3D_ID)
# Number of images: 2, mean observations per image: 2
1 0.851773 0.0165051 0.503764 -0.142941 -0.737434 1.02973 3.74354 1 P1180141.JPG
2362.39 248.498 58396 1784.7 268.254 59027 1784.7 268.254 -1
2 0.851773 0.0165051 0.503764 -0.142941 -0.737434 1.02973 3.74354 1 P1180142.JPG
1190.83 663.957 23056 1258.77 640.354 59070
```

Then I want to import it into Blender.
So I wrote the following code.
First I read the text, and split it to quaternion and translation.
And then calculate optical center use **-R^T*t**, and camera rotation use **R^T**

```py
colmap_pose = r"/Users/chunibyo/Desktop/images.txt"
rc_pose = r'flight_log.csv'
image_list_file = r'select.bat'
pose_list_file = r'blender.py'

import math

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d


def euler_from_quaternion(x, y, z, w):
    """
    Convert a quaternion into euler angles (roll, pitch, yaw)
    roll is rotation around x in radians (counterclockwise)
    pitch is rotation around y in radians (counterclockwise)
    yaw is rotation around z in radians (counterclockwise)
    """
    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + y * y)
    roll_x = math.atan2(t0, t1)

    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2
    t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
    pitch_y = math.asin(t2)

    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (y * y + z * z)
    yaw_z = math.atan2(t3, t4)

    return roll_x, pitch_y, yaw_z  # in radians


def quaternion_rotation_matrix(q0, q1, q2, q3):
    # w, x, y ,z
    """
    Covert a quaternion into a full three-dimensional rotation matrix.

    Input
    :param Q: A 4 element array representing the quaternion (q0,q1,q2,q3)

    Output
    :return: A 3x3 element matrix representing the full 3D rotation matrix.
             This rotation matrix converts a point in the local reference
             frame to a point in the global reference frame.
    """
    # Extract the values from Q

    # First row of the rotation matrix
    r00 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q1 * q1) - 1
    r01 = 2 * (q1 * q2 - q0 * q3)
    r02 = 2 * (q1 * q3 + q0 * q2)

    # Second row of the rotation matrix
    r10 = 2 * (q1 * q2 + q0 * q3)
    r11 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q2 * q2) - 1
    r12 = 2 * (q2 * q3 - q0 * q1)

    # Third row of the rotation matrix
    r20 = 2 * (q1 * q3 - q0 * q2)
    r21 = 2 * (q2 * q3 + q0 * q1)
    r22 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q3 * q3) - 1

    # 3x3 rotation matrix
    rot_matrix = np.array([[r00, r01, r02],
                           [r10, r11, r12],
                           [r20, r21, r22]])

    return rot_matrix


def rotmat2qvec(R):
    Rxx, Ryx, Rzx, Rxy, Ryy, Rzy, Rxz, Ryz, Rzz = R.flat
    K = np.array([
        [Rxx - Ryy - Rzz, 0, 0, 0],
        [Ryx + Rxy, Ryy - Rxx - Rzz, 0, 0],
        [Rzx + Rxz, Rzy + Ryz, Rzz - Rxx - Ryy, 0],
        [Ryz - Rzy, Rzx - Rxz, Rxy - Ryx, Rxx + Ryy + Rzz]]) / 3.0
    eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eigh(K)
    qvec = eigvecs[[3, 0, 1, 2], np.argmax(eigvals)]
    if qvec[0] < 0:
        qvec *= -1
    return qvec


def qvec2rotmat(qvec):
    # w, x, y, z
    return np.array([
        [1 - 2 * qvec[2] ** 2 - 2 * qvec[3] ** 2,
         2 * qvec[1] * qvec[2] - 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[3],
         2 * qvec[3] * qvec[1] + 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[2]],
        [2 * qvec[1] * qvec[2] + 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[3],
         1 - 2 * qvec[1] ** 2 - 2 * qvec[3] ** 2,
         2 * qvec[2] * qvec[3] - 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[1]],
        [2 * qvec[3] * qvec[1] - 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[2],
         2 * qvec[2] * qvec[3] + 2 * qvec[0] * qvec[1],
         1 - 2 * qvec[1] ** 2 - 2 * qvec[2] ** 2]])


def main():
    with open(colmap_pose) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    rc_lines = []
    image_list = []
    pose_list = []
    point_cloud = []

    accuracy = 10
    for index, temp_line in enumerate(lines):
        line = temp_line.strip()
        if not line.startswith('#') and (line.endswith('.png') or line.endswith('jpg')):
            temp = line.split(' ')

            qw = float(temp[1])
            qx = float(temp[2])
            qy = float(temp[3])
            qz = float(temp[4])

            tx = float(temp[5])
            ty = float(temp[6])
            tz = float(temp[7])

            name = temp[9]

            rotation_matrix = qvec2rotmat([qw, qx, qy, qz])
            optical_center = -rotation_matrix.T @ np.array([tx, ty, tz])
            tx = float(optical_center[0])
            ty = float(optical_center[1])
            tz = float(optical_center[2])

            _qw, _qx, _qy, _qz = rotmat2qvec(rotation_matrix.T)
            roll_x, pitch_y, yaw_z = euler_from_quaternion(_qx, _qy, _qz, _qw)

            rc_lines.append(
                f"{name},{tx},{ty},{tz},{accuracy},{accuracy},{accuracy},{math.degrees(yaw_z)},{math.degrees(pitch_y)},{math.degrees(roll_x)},{accuracy},{accuracy},{accuracy}\n")
            image_list.append(f"xcopy {name} select\n")

            # f"camera_object{index}.rotation_euler = Euler(({yaw_z}, {pitch_y}, {roll_x}), 'ZYX')\n" \
            # f"camera_object{index}.rotation_quaternion = Quaternion(({qw}, {qx}, {qy}, {qz}))\n" \
            blender_script = f"camera_data{index} = bpy.data.cameras.new(name='{name}')\n" \
                             f"camera_object{index} = bpy.data.objects.new('{name}', camera_data{index})\n" \
                             f"bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(camera_object{index})\n" \
                             f"camera_object{index}.location = ({tx}, {ty}, {tz})\n" \
                             f"camera_object{index}.rotation_euler = Euler(({yaw_z}, {pitch_y}, {roll_x}), 'ZYX')\n" \
                             f"camera_object{index}.rotation_mode = 'ZYX'\n" \
                             f"bpy.data.cameras['{name}'].lens = 30\n\n"
            pose_list.append(blender_script)

            point_cloud.append([tx, ty, tz])

    # selected image
    with open(image_list_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('@echo off\nmkdir select\n')
        f.writelines(image_list)

    # blender
    with open(pose_list_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('import bpy\nfrom mathutils import Euler, Quaternion\n\n')
        f.writelines(pose_list)

    # ply
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.array(point_cloud))
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud("pcl.ply", pcd, write_ascii=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I got the wrong rotation of the camera，the original pose and the imported pose are shown in the figure.
[image: colmap camera pose]
[image]

Could you give me some help, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After loading R and T try this and use quaternions for camera direction.

```
w2c = np.eye(4)
w2c[:3,:3] = R
w2c[:3,3] = T
c2w = np.linalg.inv(w2c)

# quaternions
q = Rotation.from_matrix(c2w[:3, :3).as_quat()

# translation
t = c2w[:3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is correct but you have to take the negative of the translation

```
t = -t
```

I don't know why but it works, maybe I can spare someone the trouble of having to find out themselves. This would be the full conversion (but you can also use the one form the original post).

```
w2c = np.eye(4)
w2c[:3,:3] = R
w2c[:3,3] = T
c2w = np.linalg.inv(w2c)

# Quaternions.
q = Rotation.from_matrix(c2w[:3, :3).as_quat()

# Translation.
t = c2w[:3, 3]

# The important part.
t = -t
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI there is a really nice plugin for blender that will import your colmap models (and cameras) directly into blender (it adjusts focal lengths and principal points in blender but not distortion)

This is the one i use
https://github.com/SBCV/Blender-Addon-Photogrammetry-Importer

though there is an older one here too:
https://github.com/stuarta0/blender-photogrammetry

[image]